# Executing mysql command using a batch file

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql. I've been trying to run a query through windows notepad batch file. The code on the file is:

```
USE menagerie 
SELECT type FROM event
```

The directory I typed on mysql command line is:

```
C:/Users/abu/Desktop/ev.txt
```

The output is: `->` 
indicating something must be added to complete the command. Please tell me what is missing to complete the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `source` command to execute queries from a file.

```
mysql> source C:/Users/abu/Desktop/ev.txt
```

Also, the file needs to have `;` between queries. So the first line should be

```
USE menagerie;
```

Comment: I implemented your correction without the single quote enclosure on the source file and it worked out. Thank you for the correction.